# Different return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this code block:

```
        let projectTypes: ProjectType[] = [
            ...realm.objects<ProjectType>('ProjectType')
        ].map((projectType) => {
            const icons = Object.values(
                projectType.icons_stringify ?? {}
            ).map((item) => {
                const parsedItem: MuStatusIconObj = JSON.parse(item);
                const iconUri = createUriFromBase64(
                    parsedItem.base64Data,
                    'png'
                );
                return { ...parsedItem, iconUri };
            });
            projectType.icons = icons;
            return projectType;
        });
```

And everything works as expected (array of objects with all projectType keys and values + icons array); I get the values as expected. But I just wonder why if I change these two lines:

```
projectType.icons = icons;
return projectType;
```

To this:

```
return { ...projectType, icons }
```

I get projectTypes as an array of objects with only the 'icons' key and its value (without the keys and values of projectType). Just wondering why it's happening?

Comment: `...projectType` only copies the enumerable own properties from `projectType`, so if the properties you're seeing are on the prototype, or are not enumerable (usually they'll appear greyed out if they're not enumerable in the console), then that could be a reason.

Comment: What is `ProjectType`? What does `realm.objects('ProjectType')` return?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with class instances, the spread syntax `{...object}` only copies over the instance's own enumerable properties. It does not copy non-enumerable properties or methods defined on the class's prototype. Specifically, it will not include:

- **Non-enumerable properties**: These are properties that are not listed in *for...in* loops and are not returned by `Object.keys()` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.
- **Prototype chain properties**: Methods and properties defined on the class (in its prototype) are not copied because the spread syntax only deals with the instance’s own properties.

For example, if you have a class like this:

```
class ProjectType {
    constructor(icons) {
        this.icons = icons;
    }

    getIcons() {
        return this.icons;
    }
}
```

And you create an instance and use the spread syntax on it:

```
let instance = new ProjectType(icons);
let copiedInstance = {...instance};
```

In `copiedInstance`, you would get only the `icons` property and not the `getIcons` method, because `getIcons` is on `ProjectType`'s prototype, not directly on the instance object itself.